# Deny access to all files but index.php but allow GET variables

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Basically I do not want people that visit my site to get all of the files, but all the things I tried and found on the internet disallow the usage of GET variables after the index.php. I'm using a rewrite to make domain.com/lol go to index.php?lol.

This is my current .htaccess file, if you'd like to modify it to make it easier for me, go ahead too.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]

RewriteRule .? http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^act/(.*)$ index.php?act=$1
RewriteRule ^code/(.*)$ index.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?login
RewriteRule ^logout$ index.php?logout
RewriteRule ^add$ index.php?add
RewriteRule ^tac$ index.php?tac
RewriteRule ^profile$ index.php?profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Following rule stops direct requests to index.php (either with or without) arguments:

```
# block direct requests to index.php and redirect it to /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /
```

If needed, you can change the rewrite target and/or add some more conditions based on what exactly is allowed and what's not.